# Grouping ios push notification targets

Tags: ios, push

It is possible to group,filter or exclude some of the push notifications receivers? Or every notification will be received by all receivers? Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A push notification is sent to a single device only. Once it hits the device, if the user opts to open the app from the push, i.e. they tap the "View" button, it gets received by your `UIApplicationDelegate` instance (i.e. object conforming to the `UIApplicationDelegate` protocol) which is where you process it.

So in both of the places where you interact with the push notification system, there is just 1 entity you are dealing with. That is, you are pushing to a single device and when you receive it in your app it's a single instance that receives the data. So I'm not entirely sure what you mean when you want to group or filter some receivers.

If you mean that you want to only push to some of the devices that are registered then that is entirely up to your server. If you don't want to code this yourself then I suggest taking a look at something like http://urbanairship.com/ because they do a service where they handle all the server side of push notifications for you and give you facilities such as groups.

Further reading:

- http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW10

Comment: Thanks, it was what i was asking to know.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this now using our SDK (I'm CEO). It lets you target your Mobile App users by various criteria pulled from our Mobile App Analytics collector, so for example: to users of an App Version, iOS Version, Device Type... etc. [www.AskingPoint.com](http://www.AskingPoint.com)